# custom field not show

Tags: .net, web-services, sharepoint

I have make a custom textfield and put a default value in. That's working good but the value i wanne have in the textfield is using a webservice. When i try to initiate the webservice the custom field doesn't show anymore. I initiate my webservice like this 
public CusterNameService.ServiceSoapClient demo = new CusterNameService.ServiceSoapClient();
I do nothing more than just this and it's don't render my textfield anymore. Someone?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code you are using to render the custom field, there is not much we can help with.

Also, have you looked throught the SharePoint logs to find out if the custom field rendered has logged any errors.